# Unexpected module 'BrowserAnimationsModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

This is my app.module i try to complete whole instructions in material.angular.io

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrandComponent } from './brand/brand.component';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BrandComponent,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What i should do handle this error

Comment: I believe BrowserAnimationsModule is an import, not a declaration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Move your Modules to your imports Array, declarations are for declaring your components

```
    imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
    BrowserModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
  ],
```

Comment: just app.module or where ever ? i added but still some problem. like this

Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'BrowserAnimationsModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: Do you have angular cdk and animations installed? `npm install --save @angular/cdk @angular/animations`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
  ],
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

declarations for Components, imports for Modules